# Date Issue with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just working on a simple Ruby on Rails application that keeps the data information of staff, but I realized that I needed a way to check that the date of employment will definitely need to be the beginning of the date of resignation.

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :date_of_employment %><br />
   <%= f.date_select :date_of_employment, :start_year =>1990 %>
</div>
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :date_of_resignation %><br />
   <%= date_select :date_of_resignation, :start_year => Time.now %>
```

Comment: sorry, but can you explain your problem?

Comment: nash, what i'm trying to do is that after you enter the date of employment, it will not be possible to enter a date earlier than that date for the date of resignation, as it is there is nothing controlling that

Comment: I think the only way to accomplish that is to write some javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [validates timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness) gem, if you are happy to add outside code to your project. It adds all kinds of time/date based validations.

Including validating that one field is before/after another. For instance, the following commands could be used in you model:

```
validates_datetime :date_of_resignation, :after => :date_of_employment
```

This gem doesn't rely on javascript to work, it's pure Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple solution you can consider is to have a javascript function to verify these two date on form submit. This way your server does not need to process invalid data.

We can perform validation at Rails model level before saving to database. For example these lines of code in the model will validate the data before saving

```
validate :verify_date
def verify_date
   errors.add("Invalid date") if date_of_resignation < date_of_employment
end
```

Comment: And what happens if the user turns Javascript off and then the server *does* get invalid data?

Comment: You can validate in the your Rails model as well. Something like :validate verfy_dates where verify_dates is a function, use errors.add to pass in the error. Rails wont save the data to database and you can  return the errors in the view with your_model_instance.errors

Comment: @Ethan, can u please give more insight on the way to right it in the model